# How to generate SQL Code to update 9k rows with values for one column

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I need to update one field for 9000 rows with random information on it.

Keep in mind that the table in question does not have Primary Key.

What's the best option to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. What are the 9000 rows - are they ALL the rows in the table? Or a random selection of them? Or how else are they identified? What is the data type of the "field" (please say "column" instead!) - NUMBER, DATE, VARCHAR2, ... ? How do you define "best"?

Comment: https://mockaroo.com/

Comment: IMO, you should use cursor for updating 9k rows.

Comment: @MarcGiroux, anything wrong with UPDATE statement?

Answer (score -1):

**Create table to hold 9000 random numbers for demonstration purposes:**

```
CREATE TABLE brianl.random
(
    VALUE   NUMBER
  , id      INTEGER
);
```

**Insert 9000 rows into the table**

Since this is for demonstration purposes, I decided to use a PL/SQL loop as it is easy to understand even if you are not familiar with PL/SQL. I could just as easily used a Common Table Expression (CTE), but if you don't understand the PL/SQL, you won't understand the CTE

```
DECLARE
    l_cnt   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. 9000
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO random (id)
             VALUES (i);
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

    SELECT COUNT (*) c
      INTO l_cnt
      FROM random;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('-- ' 
            || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') 
            || ' count is: ' 
            || l_cnt);
END;

-- 2016.11.11 10:28:42 count is: 9000
```

**Update 9000 records with random values with a single update statement**
 Now that we have a table of 9000 values, we can update 9000 values as requested`.

```
update random set value = dbms_random.value;
commit;
```

-- You can see those 9000 random values with a select from the table we
 created for this purpose

```
select * from random;
```

**Alternatives to PL/SQL for creating table records**

And finally, some people have commented that the PL/SQL is bad practice for creating the values (I disagree, to me it is straightforward, and because it is procedural, easy to understand for the beginner), Here is a CTE that performs the same function. Don't forget to commit after it has finished executing.

```
INSERT INTO random (id)
    WITH iset (num)
         AS (SELECT 1
               FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT num + 1
               FROM iset
              WHERE num < 9000)
    SELECT *
      FROM iset;
```

Another method people sometimes use is to select from all_objects. I personally don't care for this method as I believe that tables should only be used for their stated purpose. This is also defective if you need to go above the number of objects in all_objects, which on the system I am using is 82,009,

```
INSERT INTO random (id)
    SELECT ROWNUM
      FROM all_objects
     WHERE ROWNUM <= 9000;
```

So, on the Oracle system I am creating these demonstrations on, the following will only insert 82009 rows into the table, not the requested 100000.

```
INSERT INTO random (id)
    SELECT ROWNUM
      FROM all_objects
     WHERE ROWNUM <= 100000;
```

Comment: Dudu: I was just generating an example. I don't know why this is a "terrible way to generate rows." The update command is what is doing the work. What do you consider a better way? A recursive CTE? For 9000 rows it doesn't really matter.

Comment: This is also code with no explanation. If OP could look and code and "figure it out" they probably wouldn't be here in the first place.

Comment: We be should careful about what we teach by example. Anything would be better than inserting row by row. And it is not all about performance but also about the unneeded complexity of the code and about choosing PL/SQL over SQL. I wouldn't want to see a code like this in any context.

Comment: Dudu, I heartily disagree with you that this is a "bad" example. It is simple, easy to understand, and since it is only 9000 records on a single column, performance is not an issue. I would rather a rookie have an easy-to-understand example than a confusing, but efficient piece of code. Furthermore, rather than just criticizing which is easy, provide an alternative. I just edited my response to include two other alternatives, where is yours? 

Tankendarkk is correct, I should have included comments (which I have added) as we are dealing with a newbie.